Having issues while creating file in pycharm
I am new to python; When I was trying to create a project using pycharm then created main.py file is only being visible for 4-5 seconds after that It suddenly just disappears. I am trying this 3-4 days but nothing happened I have tried following numerous videos but they did not have any this kind of issues. Can anyone help me regarding this; please
pycharm window
This is what I am getting

i use vscode which has an integrated terminal. i would assume that pycharm has the same.  Alternatively, run the code from the terminal.

do you mean it disappears from folder? Did you try to download other version and reinstall it? Maybe it is problem only in some version and you have to use older one or wait for newer one. You could also start PyCharm in console/terminal to see if it displays error messages in console when you create file main.py. You could also check in system what you get in project's folder. Maybe file exists but doesn't have privileges, or maybe it has wrong name. Or maybe you have some external program which deletes it.

perhaps try closing Pycharm and delete the .idea/ folder as suggested in this answer PyCharm doesn’t see files in project
